# Upload csv into QGIS

Tags: qgis-3

I'm trying to import an Excel sheet into QGIS3.

[image]

For that, I saved my spreadsheet as a .csv and in QGIS I went to "Layer->add Layer-> add delimited text layer..."

Unfortunately, I get the following screen.

[image]

Apparently, QGIS doesn't recognize the different fields from the original spreadsheet. Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your [CSV](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV_(Dateiformat)#Dateiaufbau) is separated by semicolon. This is common in Germany and other european countries. But "standard" is comma, as it is used in the US.

Change the seperator to "Benutzerdefiniert" ("custom delimiters") and select semicolon. You will then get your columns correctly. Then you can also choose your geometry columns.

You may also want to select "Use comma as decimal separator" in case you have real numbers in your dataset. Also you may want to check "first record has fieldnames" to get your fieldnames as headline.

Comment: Yes, that was the solution to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: ahh ok I understand! Thanks